# Bash: как вставить значение высоты в команду convert?

Tags: изображения, resize, bash, linux

Нужно для  over 1k  сделать превью средствами bash. 
Нашёл, что можно вот такой простой командой:

```
convert -resize 200 -quality 90 1.jpg 1_m.jpg
```

Но на выходе получается 200 пикселей ширина, а надо высота.
Всё остальное - работает (перебор всех изображений в папке).

UPD: картинки не квадратные... поэтому не могу указать высоту, и они разные по формату.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну так напишите полностью:

```
convert -resize 200x200 -quality 90 1.jpg 1_m.jpg
```

Если нужна только высота, а ширину подгонять автоматом, тогда так:

```
convert -resize x200 -quality 90 1.jpg 1_m.jpg
```

Comment: Картинки не квадратные (я видел такое решение, но не предусмотрел это в вопросе).